# Randomizing Matrix in Enthought Canopy Python

Tags: python, enthought, canopy

```
matrix = MatrixCreate(1,50)

Randomize=numpy.random.random()

print Randomize(matrix)
```

By trying out the above code, I get error as "'float' object is not callable ".

Comment: Start trying to read at least a little bit of documentation (for example on [numpy.random.random](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.random.html)). It will help you in the long run. Maybe start by googling what the error means and work backwards from there.

Comment: Thank you for your direction, it was helpful.